# Subsolution of Laplace equation and supremum

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

A subsolution of the Laplace equation is a function $v$ such that

\begin{align}
\Delta v &\geq 0 \quad \text{ in } \Omega \\
v &\leq f \quad \text{ on } \partial \Omega
\end{align}

Let $u$ be a solution of the Dirichlet problem

\begin{align}
\Delta u &= 0 \quad \text{ in } \Omega \\
u &= f \quad \text{ on } \partial \Omega
\end{align}

Show without using the maximum principle that $u(x) = \sup \{ v(x): \text{v is a subsolution} \}$.

My idea: If $v$ is less or equal that $f$ then $v$ is also less or equal than $u$ on $\partial \Omega$. But how could I go on from here?

EDIT:

Could somebody please check my new idea?

Assume the contrary, i.e. $v(x) > u(x)$ for all $x$.

Since $\Delta u=0$ it follows from the weak maximum primciple that the maximum of $|u|$ in the closure of $\Omega$ is attained at the boundary which is $|f|$. For $\Delta v \geq0$ we see that the maximum of $v$ in the closure of $\Omega$ is also attained at the boundary where it is $f$.

We see that $|u| \leq |f|$ and $v\leq f \leq |f|$ so u and v are bounded by the same boundary which is a contradiction to the assumption that v is always greater than u.

Comment: I think if you just follow the proof of the maximum principle, you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=v-u$ and then $w$ satisfies
\begin{align}
-\Delta w \leq 0 \text{ in } \Omega, \ w\leq 0\text{ on } \partial \Omega. \tag{1}
\end{align}
What you need to show
$$\sup\{w(x), w \text{ satifies (1)}\}=0.\tag2$$
Clearly $0$ satisfies (1). Now you have to show that if $w$ satisfies (1), then $w\le0$ in $\bar\Omega$, which is easy (you can try yourself). So (2) holds.